# default copy assignment operator doesn't pass the is_copy_assignable test

Tags: c++, c++14

```
#include <type_traits>

struct A {};
struct B {
  B(A& a) : a(a) {}
  //B& operator=(B const& b) = default;                  // LINE 1
  //B& operator=(B const& b) { a = b.a; return *this; }  // LINE 2

  A& a;
};

static_assert(std::is_copy_constructible<B>::value, ""); // pass
static_assert(std::is_copy_assignable<B>::value, "");    // fail

int main() {
  A a;
  B b(a);
  return 0;
}
```

Compiler: g++ 5.1

The default copy constructor is fine, but the default copy assignment operator fails (even with LINE 1 uncommented).

Declaring it explicitly (uncommenting LINE 2) works though. Is it a bug?

Comment: You can't reassign references.

Comment: @Kerrek Why does LINE 2 works?

Comment: @Nubcase: Do you know what references are? With `int a; int & r = a;` you can say `r = 10;` and modify the object referred to by `r`, which is the same object as `a`, but you cannot make `r` refer to a *different* object.

Comment: @Kerrek I see. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it's not a bug. Your class doesn't have a defined copy assignment operator, because you have a reference member. If you have a class with reference semantics, it is not obvious whether you would want assignment to just assign from one reference to another (which results in copy assigning the referenced object), or whether the reference should be rebound (something you can't actually do, although this is usually what you would *want*). So the standard simply doesn't generate a default assignment operator, but allows you to define one manually with the semantics you want.